# get a subarray with a range of indexes in VB

Tags: vb.net

In other languages if I have an array I can just take a slice of this array with `this_array[starting_index..ending_index]`.

Is there something similar in VB? I didn't find anything like that in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can approach this.  Neither of them is directly on `System.Array`, which may be why you didn't find them in the docs.

One option is `ArraySegment(Of T)`.  One of its constructors takes the source array, the first index, and the count of items.  In your case, you would write:

```vb
Dim myArray As Integer() = '... whatever

'...

Dim segment = New ArraySegment(Of Integer)(myArray, 
                                           starting_index, ending_index - starting_index + 1)
```

`ArraySegment(Of T)` implements `ICollection(Of T)` and `IList(Of T)`, which I would argue is actually a terrible idea (a violation of LSP) because it throws `NotSupportedException` on the modifying operations.

Another option is to use Linq, which will give you an `IEnumerable(Of T)` (which can be converted into an array using `ToArray` or a `List(Of T)` using `ToList`):

```vb
Dim myArray As Integer() = '... whatever

'...

Dim segment = myArray.Skip(starting_index).Take(ending_index - starting_index + 1)
```

The `Skip` can be elided if `starting_index` is the array lower bound (which is usually 0).

Still another option would be to use `Array.Copy` to do it.  This requires explicitly allocating the destination array.

```vb
Dim myArray As Integer() = '... whatever

'...

Dim segment As Integer()
ReDim segment(0 To ending_index - starting_index)
Array.Copy(myArray, starting_index, segment, 0, ending_index - starting_index + 1)
```

Comment: What does ``LSP`` refer to? Does "Neither of them is directly on System.Array" mean that I can't just slice them like in C# even if both work on .NET?

Comment: LSP refers to "Liskov Substitution Principle" which holds that the behavior of subtypes should be consistent with supertypes.  C# array slicing is from C# 8 which is after Microsoft stopped adding new features to VB.  You can get the equivalent by using using the Linq call sequence I provided and adding a call to `ToArray` to the end of it; it may not be quite as efficient as the compiler may not inline the function calls.

Comment: Note that the C# 8 array slicing is probably effectively syntactic sugar around another possibility which I didn't mention which is creation of a new array and use of `Array.Copy` with an index and length.

Comment: Thank you. What does it mean in this context? In C#, I just used ``this_array(0..3)``.

Comment: There isn't a `Slice` method (or equivalent) on `System.Array`, which means that the C# compiler turns `this_array[0..3]` into something else (other than a simple function call) when it compiles it.  I think the most likely equivalent is the third possibility in my answer since (per the answer to another SO question) the slice operation returns a new array.  Note that I edited the answer to add the third method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope it will help other people too.